# Executing an if statement inside SASS loop

Tags: sass

Within a SASS loop, I am trying to execute some code if a certain condition is met. I tried the following code but it doesn't work. Is this possible in SASS? Thanks!

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
    h#{$i} {
        color: red;
    }
    @if ($i = 2) {
        h#{$i} {
            color: yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ??

Comment: I found my mistake. The comparison operator  is the double equal not just the equal sign. In term of what I want to solve, it's not complicated. I have a three level nested ul and li elements. What I want done could be accomplished with class or nth-child() selectors but I was just trying to simplify my scss code.